# Automating cygwin commands in windows command line (and ultimately in MsBuild)

Tags: windows, command-line, msbuild, cygwin

I have a situation where I have a few cygwin commands which I wish to be run in Windows command line e.g.

```
chmod 777 /home/administrator/*
```

Currently I have to manually type in cygwin.bat, then enter the above command in cygwin.  I was wondering whether it is possible (and if so, how) to have these steps automated in Windows command line?

Ultimately I want all of the above commands to be in MsBuild to achieve full automation if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to do this is to launch windows command prompt from a batch file, then, in there, call the shell script which has the command that you want to run.

batchfile-for-cygwin.bat will contain

```
@echo off
C:\cygwin\bin\bash -li /cygdrive/c/<path-to-shell-script-location>/chmod-cmd.sh
```

And then, in chmod-cmd.sh you can just have the command.

```
chmod 777 /home/administrator/*
```

With this kind of setup, you can use it in MSBuild too, I should think. I use it in Ant scripts and it works for me.

Comment: Why is mintty.exe not used ? I want to invoke sftp commands, see http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sftp&sektion=1