# Passing command line arguments to cygwin (rsync)

Tags: cygwin

I need to pass commands to cygwin, to do an rsync for a specific folder. How would I start rsync through cygwin? I'm aware of the `.bat` file method (as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053764/automating-cygwin-commands-in-windows-command-line-and-ultimately-in-msbuild)) but that's not really efficient for let's say multithreading and neither's it's neat.

If cygwin doesn't support this, are there any alternatives which do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out, in the cygwin directory (standard: `C:\cygwin\bin\`) there's a file `rsync.exe` (if installed through the cygwin installer). This can ran through the cmd with rsync's normal parameters.