# Run the shell commands in Perl using system() function in Windows

Tags: windows, perl, shell

I am migrating some plugin from `Linux` to `Windows`.

Plugin is written using `Perl` and it has the function called `system()` that will execute the shell commands.

But I am migrating to Windows now. Any way I can run the linux command in windows using system() Per function?

Some `Perl Module` avail for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `system()` command but there are caveats.  A nice description is contained in [*Using system or exec safely on Windows*](http://blogs.perl.org/users/graham_knop/2011/12/using-system-or-exec-safely-on-windows.html). This article resulted in the [Win32::ShellQuote](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aShellQuote) module.

Comment: Problem is `awk` is not working with `system`. It is a shell command, Windows won't understand.

Comment: Ouch.  You might want to try installing Cygwin and running your perl script from inside there.

Comment: @YatinSaraiya he is trying to migrate some plugin from Linux to Windows

Comment: Yes.  Cygwin (http://cygwin.org) is a "port" of UNIX to Windows.  It comes with bash.  You can choose to install perl, awk/gawk etc.  Then the port should be relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a linux command vie Perl in a windows shell? If so, try a Linux environment like Cygwin ([www.cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com)). Otherwise you have to migrate your system calls as well.

Comment: Problem is `awk` is not working with system. It is a shell command, Windows won't understand. It is not running with any of the windows unix converter like Cygwin. It is a plugin read by other system. That time still it is Windows. Usign perl we can do something ?

Comment: Can you please provide a code example? Seems that I haven't got it so far... ;)

Comment: `system(awk '{ if($9 == "t4") print $0;}' myfile.txt )`

Comment: `system(bash -i -c 'your script')`?

Comment: Error o/p ... Error: 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Is [the question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053764/automating-cygwin-commands-in-windows-command-line-and-ultimately-in-msbuild) related to your problem? Sorry, I don't have Cygwin installed.